# Share wordpress template between themes

Tags: wordpress, file, templates

Is it possible to share a template file between WordPress themes?
If so, where should I locate it? 
I didn't even manage to share a simple myfunctions.php file between theme templates.
I tried putting the file in the wp-content/themes folder, but the
    include('../myfunctions.php'); 
fails to find the file. Am I overlooking something really simple that prevents this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't "share files" between templates. You are looking for plugin functionality.
However, if there is a WordPress specific way for doing this I would like to know too.

Comment: Ok thanks Byte, I  was surprised it looks difficult, I hate having to put same template file in each theme folder. an update nightmare - I will try some more experiments.

Comment: I think he solution is here, a plugin, but all details are nicely explained  https://www.sitepoint.com/the-ultimate-includerequire-script-for-wordpress/